# Gradient changes when ImageView is added on top of the View with the gradient

Tags: android

Here is my gradient:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#00C853"
        android:startColor="#009688"
        android:type="linear"/>
    <size
        android:width="72dp"
        android:height="72dp"/>
</shape>
```

Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    <!-- Login progress -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/login_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <View
                android:id="@+id/circle"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_background_green_gradient_color"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/circle"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/circle"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/circle"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/circle"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"/>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is what it looks like on Android Studio:

[image]

And this is what it looks like on Android 8.1:

[image]

So what is the issue, why is that white gradient added to it?

Thanks.

Comment: Try making the background of the shape drawable a solid color and see if you get that weird gradient effect at the bottom.

Comment: Didn't help. Also tried background on the `ImageView` and didn't help. Tried transparent as well and didn't help. I also tried adding `FF` to the beginning of the start and end color and didn't help.

Comment: Do you still see the white gradient at the bottom?

Comment: With the change to solid, yeah. But I guess I don't know if I'm doing it right. With this change then the white part is yellow.   `android:foreground="@drawable/circle_background_green_gradient_color"
android:background="@color/yellow_200"`

Comment: I changed the drawable to `<layer-list><solid><gradient>` and that makes it just solid. Do you have an example of how to add the solid so the gradient is on top?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the 'foreground' attribute. What element are you assigning that too? Also, try changing the solid color again but remove the drawable 'ic_add_black_24dp' and see if you still get that gradient.

Comment: The + doesn't affect the issue actually, I guess I should have mentioned that. I was assigning `foreground` to the `View` just to see if I could alter the background of the gradient and to make sure the background is what is causing the issue. It is like the gradient is using a transparency on the end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161242/discussion-between-wade-wilson-and-casolorz).